# Save ACL if parent folder does not have the same permissions as the current

Tags: powershell, permissions, user-permissions, get-childitem

My goal is to read the user permissions of the folders of a drive and save it to a file.

The script should check the permission of the parent folder and compare it to the current folder. If the permissions are equal to the current folder they shouldn't be saved.

My attempt was the following:

```
ls -r | Where-Object { $_.mode -notmatch "a" } | %{ 
    $path = Get-Location 
    if(((Get-Location | Get-Acl).AccessToString) -ne (((Get-Item $path).parent.FullName) | Get-Acl).AccessToString){
        Get-Location | Get-Acl | Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" c:\ACL1.csv
     }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't know the execution process of the `ls` (`Get-Childitem`) Command and how I can address the ls "execution list" ... the try with $path failed with a defect note

Comment: Please take a look at the answer below if this helped or answered your question upvote or accept it. If the answer did not answer your question please write a comment as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse `
    | Where-Object{ $_.PSIsContainer -eq $true } `
    | ForEach-Object { 
        $currentACL = Get-Acl $_.FullName
        $parentACL = Get-Acl ($_.FullName | Split-Path -Parent)
        if($currentACL.AccessToString -ne $parentACL.AccessToString ){
            $currentACL | Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" c:\ACL1.csv -Append
        }
     }
```

This will recuse through a directory checking permissions on the current folder against its parent folder (one level up). If the permissions do not match then the current folder's `ACL` is appended to `CSV` file `c:\ACL1.csv`.